# update hidden field value in repeater with jquery

Tags: jquery, .net

I would like to update the value of a hidden field which sits next to a textbox. The reason for this is because it is inside a .net repeater so i can't update it from code behind without a postback, which takes too long.

HTML

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTranslations" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTranslations_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="rptRow" runat="server" class="form-line-input">
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnglish" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text="" Width="475px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenRecordId" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "recordId") %>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenUpdated" runat="server" Value='false' />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLanguage" runat="server" CssClass="jq-translation" Text="" Width="475px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

the JQUERY
I have used 'name' because when the html is returned to the browser the name is 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptTranslations$ctl00$hiddenUpdated' and the ID had additional text at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('.jq-translation').change(function () {
                    $(this).closest("[name$='hiddenUpdated']").val("true");
                });
            });
```

the value of the hidden field is not changing when the textbox is updated.

Comment: Have you tried with `id*=hiddenUpdated`?

Comment: closest traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM tree and not the siblings. So, try and use http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried following, it works. Use `.prev()` instead of `.closest()`. If you look closely, you need prev element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.jq-translation').change(function () {
            $(this).prev().val("true");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the hidden field in html source, or using firbug and make sure it is the name you are looking for in your jquery selector.

So I suggest add a class to this hidden field and use it in your jquery selector instead of the name because it will be auto generated by asp.net

Comment: would ClientIDMode="Static" work on a repeater though?

Comment: I changed my answer, because static Id will not work in your case

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the 'name' ends with 'hiddenUpdated', How about using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.jq-translation').change(function () {
        $(this).siblings().filter("[name$='hiddenUpdated']").val("true");
    });
});
```

Also, please see my comment to your question as well, as to why I used siblings().